# Docker-compose - passing environment variables to Flask using script

Tags: bash, docker, variables, docker-compose

This my project strcuture at host:

```
   set_env_vars.sh
              dev/
                 docker-compose-dev.yml
                 /services/
                          web/
                             .env-dev?  <------
                             project/
                                    config.py
                                    api/
                                       resources/
                                                auth.py
```

---

**set_env_vars.sh**

```
export SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID=my_id
export SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET=my_secret
export SPOTIFY_REDIRECT_URI=http://localhost
export SPOTIFY_CACHE_PATH=/project/api/auth/spotify/.cache
```

which I run like so:

```
$ source ./set_env_vars.sh
```

---

**docker-compose-dev.yml**

```
services:

  web:
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=development
      - APP_SETTINGS=project.config.DevelopmentConfig
      - SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID=${SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID}
      - SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET=${SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET}
      - SPOTIFY_REDIRECT_URI=${SPOTIFY_REDIRECT_URI}
      - SPOTIFY_CACHE_PATH=${SPOTIFY_CACHE_PATH}
```

---

config.py

```
class DevelopmentConfig(BaseConfig):
    SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID = os.environ.get('SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID')
    SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET = os.environ.get('SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET')
    SPOTIFY_REDIRECT_URI_ = os.environ.get('SPOTIFY_REDIRECT_URI')
    SPOTIFY_CACHE_PATH = os.environ.get('SPOTIFY_CACHE_PATH')
```

---

**auth.py**

```
from project.config import DevelopmentConfig

sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(
      DevelopmentConfig.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID,
      DevelopmentConfig.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET,
      DevelopmentConfig.SPOTIFY_REDIRECT_URI,
      scope=DevelopmentConfig.SCOPE, 
      cache_path=DevelopmentConfig.SPOTIFY_CACHE_PATH))
```

---

But I'm getting the following error:

```
spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOauthError: No client_id. Pass it or set a SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID environment variable.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: A typo? The error requests you set `SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID`, but the vars you set begin `SPOTIFY_`.  Could this be the problem?

Comment: yes, but regardless of the name of the variable, it complains about the variable not having any value, no?. the value is set with Spotify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This certainly looks like you need to pass the variables with the `SPOTIPY_` spelling, as per [the docs](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.9.0/?highlight=auth_manager#authorization-code-flow).

However I also noted that your code repeats the same variable names several times.  Possibly this could lead to typos as you try to maintain the same variable names across several files.

A simpler way to approach this might be to have the variables contained in a `.env-dev` file:

```
SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID=my_id
SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET=my_secret
SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI=http://localhost
SPOTIPY_CACHE_PATH=/project/api/auth/spotify/.cache
```

Then load these in your `docker-compose-dev.yml` file:

```
services:
  web:
    env_file:
      - .env-dev
```

Then in your Python code you could do:

```
import os, DevelopmentConfig

sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(
      os.environ.get('SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID'),
      os.environ.get('SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET'),
      os.environ.get('SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI'),

      scope=DevelopmentConfig.SCOPE, 

      cache_path = os.environ.get('SPOTIPY_CACHE_PATH')))
```

This method has less repitition, although loading of a configuration bypasses your `config.DevelopmentConfig` object for these variables.

However this method avoids loading the variables into the host's shell, and instead sets them inside a specific service.  It also separates secerts so you can commit `docker-compose.yml` to source control.

Comment: docker-compose is not being able t find my `.env-dev`. could you please add the correct path according to my edit at structure above?

Comment: @8-BitBorges This should be in the same directory as `docker-compose-dev.yml`

Comment: actually, it had been saved with .sh (which was not showing) and that was the problem. fixed now, thanks